# If Web API can be used just for Authentication using OAuth 2 in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, wcf-web-api

I'm working on segregating the authentication part of my ASP.net MVC4 application using DotNetOAuth 2.0, Which will means that one project will do only authentication and send out response,based on response it will have access to other application.

The Idea is to get any application or project added later on use one common authentication process.

First thing came to my mind was building a service, in the process a read a lot about Web API and think it can help to achieve what I'm looking for.

Please suggest if you guys have implemented something like this or whats's the best practice.

Should i go with API or service, any link or sample to direct is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web API is also a service - a RESTful service. The choice of using a "Service" although is good your underlying authentication platform will define what you should be using.

WCF is much more than a web service where as a Web API is pure HTTP service.

If you expect all your "applications" to be web based then there is no reason why this cannot be a Web API.

This article might be something that should help you decide on your authentication model: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm looking for standalone application which just does the authentication for all application at once using OAUTH